# How to add Attachinary input in rails active admin

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin, cloudinary

What are the necessary steps in the Rails Active Admin plugin to add Attachinary input?

Comment: Please don't move the answer back into the question; that's not how this site works. That it was moved to a community wiki answer below was the right action. If you want to repost that as your own answer, that's fine, but *do use an answer post for that*. You can then flag the other Community Wiki answer for moderator attention to request deletion.

Answer (score 1):

<sup><sub>Copied from original question.</sub></sup>

---

First step:

Add new folder named 'inputs' in 'app' folder.

In this folder, create file named 'formtastic_attachinary_input.rb'

And add these lines in this file:

```
class FormtasticAttachinaryInput
  include Formtastic::Inputs::Base
  attr_reader :attachinary_options

  def to_html
    input_wrapping do
      label_html <<
      template.builder_attachinary_file_field_tag(method, @builder, { html: input_html_options })
    end
  end
end
```

Second step:

In 'config/initializer' create a file named ‘active_admin_cloudinary.rb’

And add these lines in this file:

```
module ActiveAdmin
  module Views
    module Pages
      class Base < Arbre::HTML::Document

        alias_method :original_build_head, :build_active_admin_head

        def build_active_admin_head
          original_build_head

          within @head do
            text_node cloudinary_js_config
          end
        end

      end
    end
  end
end
```

Third Step:

In ‘app/assets/javascript’ create file named ‘active_admin.js’

And add these lines:

```
//= require active_admin/base
//= require jquery-fileupload/vendor/jquery.ui.widget
//= require jquery-fileupload/jquery.iframe-transport
//= require jquery-fileupload/jquery.fileupload
//= require cloudinary/jquery.cloudinary
//= require attachinary
//= require attachments
```

Fourth step:
Create file in ‘app/assets/javascript’ named ‘attachments.js.coffee’

And add these lines:

```
jQuery ->
  $('.attachinary-input').attachinary()
```

How to use it?

```
ActiveAdmin.register Category do
  menu priority: 3
  menu label: "Sous catégories"
  permit_params  :name, :photo, :description, :category_type_id, :id, :pos_id

  form do |f|
    f.inputs "Infos de base" do
      f.input :id
      f.input :name
      f.input :description
      f.input :category_type
      f.input :pos_id
      f.input :photo, as: :formtastic_attachinary ### THERE #### 
    end
    actions
  end

  filter :name, :as => :string
  filter :description
  filter :category_type
  filter :pos_id
end
```